# Can I reliably consume a WPF custom control in a winform?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wpfdatagrid

My requirement is to create a winform with contains a datagrid that allows rows to expand and show additional details. I'm considering using a WPF control and incorporate a WPF Datagrid in it to handle this, taking advantage of the RowDetails property of the DataGrid to handle the expansion of rows.

I'm completely new to WPF and the RowDetails property of Datagrid and so am only reading up on them now. Is it possible for me to use this control in my winform once I develop it? What issues may I face when trying to integrate the WPF control in my winform.

Answer (score 0):

I have on multiple occasions used a WPF control on a WinForm.  However, the only way I ever do it is to host it inside an ElementHost control.  Once there I haven't noticed any major issues, though I do hear performance can be suspect depending on the usage.

Answer (score 0):

As the two previous Answers state you have to use an ElementHost.
[Here](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/mixing-wpf-and-winforms/) there is a comparison on how to host WPF in Winforms and Winforms in WPF. It was good for me to read the comparison when I was starting to work with it. 
In this article the author links you to [Gotchas For Working With Windows Forms/WPF Interop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scoberry/archive/2006/09/01/735844.aspx) that has some common issues you can run into.

Build your WPF control like it was a Vendor control, with a clear interface and then just host it with the ElementHost. I have had to use it both ways but with legacy controls, and it really helps if you have a good interface in the control that you bring from the other platform, if not it can be a bit messy.